# Add groups with Lync 2010 UCMA 3.0 c#

Tags: c#, lync, ucma

I am trying to create a simple contact manager for Lync 2010 UCMA.

I'm using an `NotificationReceived` event, and testing if `IsFullNotification` flag is set. I hoped that as groups are added, there will be no "IsFullNotification".

But such an event never happens, it is always set to `true`.

How can I still get a full list of contacts with already added groups (as they are added successfully) to remap the contacts before adding the number of newly created.

P.S. Translated using translate.google.com

```
_contactGroupServices.NotificationReceived += OnNotificationReceived;
_contactGroupServices.BeginSubscribe(ar =>
{
   try
   {
      _contactGroupServices.EndSubscribe(ar);
   }
   catch (RealTimeException rtex)
   {
       Console.WriteLine(rtex);
   }
}
, null);
```

the handler:

```
void OnNotificationReceived(object sender, ContactGroupNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Received a contact update.");

    if (e.IsFullNotification) //always this value :(
    {
        ExtractContactGroupInfo(e);
        AddGroups();
    }
    else
    {
        HandleAddedGroupNotification(e); // The LINE
    }
}
```

I've marked the line that I need to execute when all groups were added. And also I will need current value of `ContactGroupNotificationEventArgs e`.

Comment: I even try to call BeginSubscribe after fll groups was added, but there an eroor occured: "the data session is in an invalid staate to establish".

Comment: I've tried to correct the translation a bit, please check whether it 'sounds well' to you. I might have accidentially changed something if I understood you wrong. Also, I could not grasp the meaning of the last "how can I still get(..)" sentence, so I left it as-is. You can try to post the text in two languages, one translated and one original - that way, someone can accuratelly fix the translation errors :) BTW. If "Roman" is the Polish first name, I can help next time:)

Answer (score 3):

I too had this same issue, this is because your call to BeginSubscribe is made but the subscription is not complete. Make sure that before you add a group the _contactGroupService.State is subcribed. If not wait till it becomes subscribed. This should hopefully resolve your issue.

Happy coding :)